# #Django - 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django

I have this code,

```
def delivery_date(request):
    today = datetime.today().date()
    results = [get(today)]
    stages = Stage.objects.prefetch_related('Stage').all()

    for i in range(3):
        results.append(get(results[i]))

    results = [{'date': i} for i in results]
    stages = [{'menu': s} for s in stages]
    for i in results:
        for stage in stages:
            stage['id'] = stage['menu'].id
            stage['name'] = stage['menu'].name
            stage['desc'] = stage['menu'].desc
            stage['menu'] = stage['menu'].Stage.filter(
                delivery_date__exact=i['date'])
            stage['menu'] = serializers.serialize('python', stage['menu'])

        i['menu'] = stages
        i['date'] = i['date'].strftime('%b %-d')

    return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```

But the results says,
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwryL.png)
But if the results has only one date, it works.
Like this,

```
def delivery_date(request):
    today = datetime.today().date()
    results = [get(today)]
    stages = Stage.objects.prefetch_related('Stage').all()

    # for i in range(3):
        # results.append(get(results[i]))

    results = [{'date': i} for i in results]
    stages = [{'menu': s} for s in stages]
    for i in results:
        for stage in stages:
            stage['id'] = stage['menu'].id
            stage['name'] = stage['menu'].name
            stage['desc'] = stage['menu'].desc
            stage['menu'] = stage['menu'].Stage.filter(
                delivery_date__exact=i['date'])
            stage['menu'] = serializers.serialize('python', stage['menu'])

        i['menu'] = stages
        i['date'] = i['date'].strftime('%b %-d')

    return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```

The results,

```
[
    {
        "date" : Oct 25,
        "menu" : [
             {
                "menu" : [
                     {
                        "model" : backend.product,
                        "pk" : 13,
                        "fields" : {
                                        "name" : Tasty Tempeh,
                                        "desc" : Nasi, Ayam, Wortel, Buncis, Bawang Merah, Bawang Putih, Daun Salam, Serai, Minyak Wijen, Minyak Kelapa Sawit.,
                                        "desc_detail" : ,
                                        "delivery_date" : 2019-10-25,
                                        "avatar" : ,
                                        "stage" : 1
                                   }
                      }
                  ],
                  "id" : 1,
                  "name" : Porridge,
                  "desc" : 
             }
    }
]
```

What's wrong with my logic? Can Anyone helps?

Comment: maybe you try change `stage['menu'].id` to `stage['menu']['id']`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is in the next iterate of results. If only one data in results it works.

Answer (score 0):

it is just you missed that menu is a Dict which has a list as value say temp 
and that temp file has a dict at its 0 indexes:

use the following :

```
stage['menu'][0]['id']
```

Comment: like this? `stage['menu'][0]['id'] = stage.id` or `stage['id'] = stage['menu'][0]['id'] `. Both are error.

Comment: My mistake it is stage[0]['menu']['id'] this should work